# is Time Based log Compaction in Kafka based on Wall Clock time or Event time or a mix of Both?

Tags: apache-kafka

I have been trying to understand how to set time based log compaction, but still can't understand its behavior properly. In particular i am  interested in the behavior of **log.roll.ms.**

What I would like to understand is the following statement taken from the official kafka doc: https://kafka.apache.org/documentation.html#upgrade_10_1_breaking

> The log rolling time is no longer depending on log segment create time. Instead it is now based on the timestamp in the messages. More specifically. if the timestamp of the first message in the segment is T, the log will be rolled out when a new message has a timestamp greater than or equal to T + log.roll.ms

in `T + log.roll.ms`

a) I understand that T is based on the timestamp of the message and therefore can be considered the  Event Time. However what is the clock behind `log.roll.ms`. In kafka stream for instance, when working with Event time it is clear what is the stream, it is the highest timestamp seen. **So does the time for log compaction progress with the timestamp of the message and therefore is Event Time, or it progress based on the walk-clock time of the Brokers**

I thought it was event time, but then i saw the following talk https://www.confluent.io/kafka-summit-san-francisco-2019/whats-the-time-and-why/ where
@Matthias J. Sax  talks about it. From his talks i got confused. It seems indeed that compaction is driven by both  Event time `T` and Walking time